# How to specify mana usage from my mana pool?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-arena

I'm playing a 4 color deck with 4 Lotus Cobra and 4 Evolving Wilds.  It is not unusual for me to have 4-5 mana floating in my mana pool.  Managing the mana colors is important, and the "auto pay" solution will not pick the colors of mana I want it to use out of the mana pool.

Is there a way for me to specify how mana is drained from my mana pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to answers to [this question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MagicArena/comments/86w11b/how_do_i_spend_floating_mana_in_mtg_arena_i_am/):

If you have a mana pool with specific colors that you want spent specific ways:

- Switch to full control mode by pressing Ctrl + Shift.
- Cast the spell by dragging it like normal.  [Note: the spell won't actually be cast.  See next step.]
- Mandatory color payments will be automatically pulled from the pool, but generic mana requirements can be paid one at a time by clicking on mana symbols.
- Once mana has been paid, spell will be cast.
- If you mis-click, you can hit Z to undo previous clicks.

Comment: I edited your answer significantly after I actually used the feature playing against Sparky.  Thanks!  I had not fully appreciated full control mode.